# Need to post huge amount of data to rest api - how to

Tags: json, node.js, angular, rest, express

I am currently developing a web service consisting of an Angular2 application and a nodejs/express REST API.
Most of the time the Angular app is sending small requests to the API, but there need to be a function where the user can upload an excel file containing between 50.000 and 100.000 records. These should be uploaded to the rest api, which is then updating/inserting the records in the database

How is the best way to achieve this?
Is it possible to send it all as one big JSON post request, or as 50.000 single request.
Is it viable to get all 50.000-100.000 records from the rest api, and let the Angular app sort duplicate records before sending the ones which needs updating or inserting.

Hope you can provide som input on this!

Best Regards Morten.

Comment: Your question as its posed is somewhat open-ended. Are you just looking for answer to 1) "can this be done", 2) what kind of architecture it should be 3) or to some specific programming issue? If you have a specific programming issue, posting code increases your likelihood for answers.

Comment: I also have a similar issue, I'm keen to find out solutions. My Conclusion push the request on a background thread, add to a queue system and allow to run in the background. Never a good idea to loop through individually and push to a single entity endpoint.

Comment: @jsalonen It needs to be done :-) my question is more like, whats the best approach to take to solve it.

Comment: @MortenDueChristiansen another suggestion, break the data into "chunks". Each request can send up 1000. Divide 1000 by the total, exposing the number of request's.

Comment: this maybe? https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

Comment: @TezWingfield will try that thank you.

Comment: @JGFMK thank you. already using this to parse the xlsx file, but need to find the best method to send all that data to the api

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to zip it and decompress it perhaps... https://coderwall.com/p/mekopw/jsonc-compress-your-json-data-up-to-80

Comment: Imo its better to stay with one request as everything else generates only more overhead. To prevent your api being blocked you may consider to build a microservice that handles those uploads. Inserting 100k entries into a db will be interesting though

Comment: Just upload the file and let the server handle it. That's the best place to validate the input. +50.000 updates takes some time, let the user keep track of the status somehow.

Comment: thanks for all the input. I have tried implementing a way, where the webapp, sends 500 records at a time, and showing user progress. In my local development environment this takes about 8-9 mins to upload all 85.000 records. will test it later on a more production like environment